# Booting up Rails for the first time, "Please install mysql2 adapter"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, compiler-errors

I have ran mysql2 install (3.11) successfully and activerecord-mysql2-adapter is in my gem list. I have run bundle install when I did created new project.

`C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:214:in 'block in replace_gem': Please install the mysql2 adapter: 'gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter' (mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)`

Please help me, I cant even get rails server running. Could my other programs be blocking rails or possibly fire wall? What program can I allow in firewall if so?

My Gemfile specifies the following.

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

My Error generated is here

```
Exiting
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:214:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resolve_hash_connection'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'

    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:720:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/i
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from C:/Users/Charlie/Documents/RailsProject/shop/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Users/Charlie/Documents/RailsProject/shop/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Charlie/Documents/RailsProject/shop/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in`instance_eval'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in`initialize'
    from C:/Users/Charlie/Documents/RailsProject/shop/config.ru:in `new'
    from C:/Users/Charlie/Documents/RailsProject/shop/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in`parse_file'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in`wrapped_app'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What does the `adapter` setting say in your `config/database.yml`?

Comment: I get weird errors like that when my database.yml has mysql and gemfile has mysql2 or vice versa.

Comment: ITs mysql2, correct. Do i need a database table already created? or does this create a data base for me (rails server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make sure that your `database.yml` file is correct. 
You should have

`adapter: mysql2`   not   `mysql/anything`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

plz check your config/database.yml file in it your structure should be like this

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: abc_development
  pool: 5
  username: your_database_username
  password: your_database_password
  host: localhost
```

for all 3 environments

and most important you should create your mysql databse for this you have mysql install on your system.give username and password to your database and add it in your database.yml file

Comment: Do i need 3 databases? abc_development, abc_test, abc_production?

Comment: Oh, so I MUST create a database before I am allowed to run `rails server`?

Comment: What command is the create database? Do I boot up MySQL Command Shell, log in and do `Create database projectname`?

Comment: follow this link it will clear all http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-database-setup.htm